# Inserting and retrieving data from myself with ' " \

Tags: php, mysql

Silly question, but can't think of the answer, ive used addslashes and removeslashes for adding data into my mysql, but when retrieving it also removes just normal \ that were not generated by the function, is there a better way to do this without using str_replace?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `str_replace()`?

Comment: Yes, by not using addslashes() nor stripslashes() but mysql_real_escape_string() to insert data into database

Comment: @RobinJ because that will add extra code

Comment: so i would just replace addslashes by mysql_real_escape_string() and wouldnt need to use removeslashes at all?

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius: Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass arguments to a database there's `mysql_real_escape_string()` for mysql_* and mysqli_*, and bindParam for PDO.
Also, when you put this in an SQL Query for example: `Hello\/World`, only `Hello/World` will be passed into the database, not the `\` wich was used to escape the `/`.

`PDO->bindParam()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
`mysql_real_escape_string()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: To extend on this answer.... `mysql_real_escape_string` will add the slashes for you. When you retrieve the data from the DB, you don't need to call `stripslashes` because the slashes never made it into the DB; they're just there so that the value gets inserted correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The backslash escapes are used to make strings valid to pass by the SQL parser. The database will not store those backslashes. When you query the database again, they will not be returned.

And btw, the correct escaping for `What'ever` is not `'What\'ever'` but `'What''ever'`. Using `addslashes()` on input strings only works if your MySQL server is in backwards-compliant mode.

Comment: No, MySQL's escaping sequence has always been a backslace. doubled single-quotes is only valid if ANSI QUOTES mode is enabled: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Comment: You're screwing my scare tactics with your damn superfluous facts!